# Change graph editor vertex setting to show class instead of id

Tags: orientdb

On querying in Graph Editor, by default `@rid` is shown.

To change that, I have to *click on the vertex* and go to **Settings -> Display** and change `@rid` to `@class`. I have to do it for all the vertices.

- Can I set a global setting to always get `@class` name instead of id?
- Can I set a local setting to get `@class` name for all the vertices of the search results?

Comment: As today it is not possible. You can raise an enhancement issue here
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/issues

Comment: @wolf4ood thanks, I raised a defect - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/issues/498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not yet supported. I raised a defect for this-

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/issues/498